# Change all characters to ASCII in JSON object

Tags: php, json, special-characters

I'm looking for a means to go through a json object and switch all characters to HTML safe characters, by using the `htmlspecialchars()` function for example.

I think I could just loop through and create a new json object with the character changes but I'm thinking there must be a more optimal way to do it?

Comment: JSON is a string--a serialized data structure using a subset of JavaScript literal syntax. Do you meant to say, rather, that you have a PHP Array which resulted from running `json_decode()` on a JSON serialized representation of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended, [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is likely the best bet:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value) {
    $value = encoding_function($value);
});
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Where `encoding_function` is your function of choice to encode the values; that could be `htmlspecialchars` or otherwise.

Alternatively, you could wrap the whole mess as a function itself:

```
function json_walk_recursive($json, callable $function) {
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value) use($function) {
        $value = $function($value);
    });
    return json_encode($array);
}

echo json_walk_recursive('{"foo":"bar","baz":{"qux":"zip"}}', function($value) {
    return strtoupper($value);
});

// {"foo":"BAR","baz":{"qux":"ZIP"}}
```

This example could be optimized in many ways; for instance passing `$function` directly to `array_walk_recursive`, however I merely expanded it for readability (*I dunno, it seems clearer in its intent to me. It **does** require the argument be by reference, so consuming code doesn't need to be aware of that detail in it's current form; but I digress*)

Additionally, you'd want error recovery and other such necessities.

Comment: Did something similar to your second suggestion, thank you kindly!